# LaTeX - Roman Numbers for the first couple of pages

Tags: numbers, latex, counting

I want that the first couple of sites of my latex documents counts in roman and later in arabic numbers.

I tried `\fronmatter` etc. but it didn't work. Also `\pagenumbering{Roman}` and switching to `\pagenumbering{arabic}` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand definieren
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Bilder einfügen
\usepackage{subfig}      % Bilder Nebeneinander ausrichten
\usepackage{natbib}      % Runde Klammern bei den Zitaten
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,~} % Bei Zitat das Komma entfernen zw. Autorname und Jahr
\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathe
\usepackage{amssymb} % mathematische Symbole, wie z.B. R der reellen Zahlen.
\usepackage{dsfont}      % Für die Identitätsfunktion 1|
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % Zitieren nach APA-Zitierrichtlinie
\usepackage{float}       % Bilder einfacher ausrichten
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Für die Referenzierung von Labels. Erstellt auch Links im PDF
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}% normale Schrift in Kopfzeile
%\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% ohne Kapitelnummer
%\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}% falls auch auf Kapitelanfangsseiten
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

... Some pages


\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}
\section{Einleitung}

\subsection{Motivation}
```

Does anyone see the problem?
Thanks in advance and greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, alright, alright... it took a little but I solved it.

The problem is the setkomafont. It overwrites the headings, so I can only use the `\pagestyle{headings}` style. That is alright for me. Cheers!